# Helper render_breadcrumbs okay in dev env but not found by cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using breadcrumbs_on_rails v1.0.1 in a Rails 2.3.10 app by including the gem in my Gemfile. In my development environment I see no problems at all - the views render as expected. In my cucumber tests though, I get the following:

```
undefined local variable or method `render_breadcrumbs' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1034c46f0> (ActionView::TemplateError)

1: = render_breadcrumbs
```

I've also tried to use

```
config.gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
```

in my `config/environment.rb` instead of including the gem in my Gemfile. I've also tried explicitly including `BreadcrumbsOnRails` in my `spec_helper.rb` without luck.

Confused as to why the `render_breadcrumbs` helper is found in the dev environment but not in test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would be working in development and not in cucumber, but `render_breadcrumbs` is provided by `BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin`.

The [breadcrumbs_on_rails README](http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/breadcrumbs_on_rails/) suggests including that mixin in ApplicationController, though it suggests this specifically for Rails 3 compatibility. It's still worth a try if nothing else is working.

Comment: Cool thanks - including that mixin specifically in each controller that uses breadcrumbs_on_rails (or in ApplicationController) fixes the issue.  Still wonder why this is not necessary in dev but is necessary in the test environment.